Flutter set dynamic home in Main.dart
A user in my app goes through registration (using Firebase as backend) before accessing the app. I have a global class method where variables are stored.
class AppData {
  static var _appdata = AppData._internal();

  var home;
  factory AppData() {
    return _appdata;
  }
  AppData._internal();
}

final appData = AppData();

The users may be from different countries and as such, depending on the country, interface and the language changes. I have no problem with that.
in the main.dart if the user has not gone through registration (or the user is not authenticated), it returns a page called RadioButton, where the user chooses a language.
Now I want to establish that if the user is authenticated, the home in the main.dart should be the HomePage of the region chosen.
Like this
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProviderss())],
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'AppName',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.black),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home:
            
            FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
                ? HomePage// Instead of the HomePage I want it to be dynamic
                : const RadioButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
} 

So instead of the HomePage, I want it to be something like this
home:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
                    ? appData.home
                    : const RadioButton(),

In my registration Page
After filling form for registration
TextButton(
         onPressed: (){
                     appData.home = nameOfHomePage;
                      }
          )

The nameOfHomePage are already defined.
When I restart my app I get this error
**════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MaterialApp(dirty, state: _MaterialAppState#949a4):
If no route is provided using home, routes, onGenerateRoute, or onUnknownRoute, a non-null callback for the builder property must be provided, and the other navigator-related properties, navigatorKey, initialRoute, and navigatorObservers, must have their initial values (null, null, and the empty list, respectively).
'package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart':
Failed assertion: line 375 pos 10: '(home != null ||
          routes.isNotEmpty ||
          onGenerateRoute != null ||
          onUnknownRoute != null)
         ||
         (builder != null &&
          navigatorKey == null &&
          initialRoute == null &&
          navigatorObservers.isEmpty)'**

How do I resolve this issue?

You can try using onGenerateRoute /builder on MaterialApp

I don't really get it. Can you use it in the code provided above please? Where should implement it?
